# Subclassing a UIView. init method is never called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a `UIView` on the interface builder. In my view controller I have an `IBOutlet MyUIView` which points to the `UIView` on the interface builder.

I changed the class of the `UIView` to "`MyUIView`" (custom UIView class) but it seems like none of the `init` methods of the subclass are fired.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you show your code how you doing it?

Comment: Nothing really in the code! In interface builder I select the UIView and sets the class to "ShadowView". I placed breakpoints in the ShadowView init method but it never goes into those methods.

Answer (score 27):

Instead of `init` you need to call `initWithCoder` first then call `init` as :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self baseClassInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)baseClassInit {

    //initialize all ivars and properties    
}
```

Comment: You also need to *implement* `initWithCoder:`, as that code does. Simply calling it from some random place while overriding `init` alone will not do the job.

Answer (score 22):

Short answer: you need to use `initWithCoder:`.

From the `initWithFrame:` docs:

> If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, this method is not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized using their initWithCoder: method, which modifies the attributes of the view to match the attributes stored in the nib file.

If you're using a nib / xib / Storyboard file, use `initWithCoder:`.  If you're creating your view programmatically, you can use `init` or `initWithFrame:`.